# Repeated Measures Mixed Model or Time Series? (Ecologist needing help)

Tags: r, time-series, mixed-model, repeated-measures, lme4-nlme

I've been reading and researching for a while now but finally decided to directly ask. My data consists of the following:

- Dependent variable: water-use measured daily over 1 year spanning three seasons
- Samples/Group: 79 trees grouped in three forest types
- Independent variables: Rain, Windspeed, rel. humidity (vpd), soil moisture, radiation

My **main research question** is: Are the effects of the independent variables (rain etc.) on water-use different in a certain forest type and season, accounting for repeated measures. I.e. in respect to average tree water-use in a given forest, does radiation play a bigger role in forest 1 during season 2, while soil moisture plays the biggest role in forest 2 during season 2?

This is what my data look like:

```
  'data.frame': 21943 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ date    : Date, format: "2015-05-28" "2015-05-29" "2015-05-30" ...
 $ season  : Factor w/ 3 levels "Wet 2015","Dry 2016",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ sample  : Factor w/ 79 levels "V10 1","V10 2",..: 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
 $ response: num  0.245 0.263 0.225 0.281 0.262 ...
 $ wind    : num  4.64 2.97 3.57 3.25 3.07 ...
 $ rad     : num  377 390 342 551 421 ...
 $ rain    : num  0.0476 0.0265 0.2011 0 0 ...
 $ soil    : num  46.1 46 46.3 46.4 46.1 ...
 $ vpd     : num  0.34 0.376 0.182 0.468 0.401 ...
 $ plot    : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

            date   season sample   response     wind       rad        rain     soil         vpd plot
1     2015-05-28 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.24480553 4.643837 377.14309 0.047625000 46.14017 0.339785813    1
2     2015-05-29 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.26295553 2.967125 390.36045 0.026458333 45.99205 0.375777035    1
3     2015-05-30 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.22522116 3.565382 341.96358 0.201083333 46.26337 0.181752693    1
4     2015-05-31 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.28107339 3.246729 551.23026 0.000000000 46.37108 0.467883884    1
5     2015-06-01 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.26156698 3.067247 421.28554 0.000000000 46.11951 0.401153543    1
6     2015-06-02 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.25699633 3.095927 419.17366 0.000000000 45.72309 0.406136619    1
7     2015-06-03 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.24547362 2.713635 341.31636 0.000000000 45.39681 0.269464323    1
8     2015-06-04 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.21283341 2.577397 289.69811 0.058208333 45.19521 0.272783912    1
9     2015-06-05 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.15540573 2.389799 193.39940 0.317500000 46.20590 0.246087874    1
10    2015-06-06 Wet 2015   V2 1 0.26724130 2.231299 492.67452 0.000000000 46.70743 0.807393387    1
```

The challenges (to me) of my data are the following:

1. all samples (trees) are subjected to the three levels of *season*, but not to the three levels of *forest*.
2. Dependent and independent variables are highly autocorrelated.
3. My independent variables are continuous while forest and season are categorical.
4. Data gaps are common and occur across different levels (i.e. ranging from missing data for a given tree [sensor failure] to missing data for an entire forest type [data logger failure]).

Again, I'm interested whether soil, wind, rain etc. *are differently important* in a given forest/season combination. I am not interested in differences in the response between forests/season (I already know those exists from a separate analysis). This is my current approach to address my research question:

```
lmer(response ~ vpd + vpd:plot + 
                rad + rad:plot +
                wind + wind:plot +
                rain + rain:plot + 
                soil + soil:plot + (1 | sample:season),
    data = new.input.data, na.action = na.exclude)
```

Am I on the right track here or do I have to delve into time series analysis?

Thank you so much for any insights on this!

Comment: with time series analysis you can model one single stochastic process (i.e. if you would have only one "water usage" series). but since you have 79 trees, I would say you are on the right track.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Given that information, I am still not sure if my mixed model actually addresses/answers my question.